# Codepen project not updating .css from .scss file

Tags: sass, codepen

CodePen doesn’t want to update my .css from the changes I’m making to the .scss file. It got the first set of changes I did, but none thereafter. Here’s the codepen: https://codepen.io/webidextrous/project/editor/ZmJQar

And here's the contents of the styles/index.scss file

```
  /**
   * index.scss
   * - Add any styles you want here!
   */

  body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width:70%;
  }

  #intro {
    background-color:#C43835;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10 10 10 10;
    margin:10 10 10 10;
  }

  #portfolio {
    background-color:#376F86;
    color:#fdf;
  }

  #contact {
    background-color:#2FC6F1
    color:#999;
  }

  #footer {
    background-color:#FBFBFF;
    color:#111;
  }
```

The following code is what it's "stuck" on and won't update to reflect what's in the .scss file.

```
  /**
   * index.scss
   * - Add any styles you want here!
   */

  body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  #intro {
    background-color: #C43835;
  }

  #portfolio {
    background-color: #376F86;
  }

  #contact {
    background-color: #2FC6F1;
  }

  #footer {
    background-color: #FBFBFF;
  }
```

What am I not understanding about how this should work? Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a semicolon on the #contact section of the .scss file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your syntax is wrong. You should add a unit (`px`, `em`, `%` etc.) to your `margin` and `padding`, otherwise it won't be rendered.

```css
padding:10 10 10 10;
margin:10 10 10 10;
```

should be

```css
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
```

Read more about setting the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) at MDN.

Here's an [example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZObvq) with SCSS that uses a variable (`$value`) of `10px` to be translated into CSS with the compilation.